# How embed bokeh server plots from one document in several places in at html file

Tags: django-templates, bokeh

I have an application that creates several "bokeh" plots. Those plots all belong to the same document, so that i can use linked panning / zooming. The plots are served by a "bokeh" server. All plots appear in one website but there is some html content between the plots. All of that is part of a django app. Using bokeh-0.12.1

```
#view.py
plots = []
plot1 = figure()
plot1.line([1,2,3],[5,4,2])
plot2 = figure()
plot3.line([1,2,3],[5,4,2])

script_tags = []
bokeh_document = curdoc()
session = push_session(bokeh_document)
script.tags.append(autoload_server(model=plot1, session_id=session.id))
script.tags.append(autoload_server(model=plot2, session_id=session.id))
```

Then in the template would look as follows:

```
template.html
<h1>These are the embedded server plots</h1>
{% for script in script_tags %}
<pre>{{ subgroup_plot.script }}</pre>
<h1>Here comes a plot</h1>
some Text

<div>
{{script | safe }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

But then the page gets rendered imporperly... The plots appear over each other and over the page content. The [documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/embed.html) does not mention how to embedd it in html. So how does it have to be done so that the css works correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are missing some CSS classes, namely `bk-root` and `plotdiv`. Try the following:

```
<h1>These are the embedded server plots</h1>
{% for script in script_tags %}
<pre>{{ subgroup_plot.script }}</pre>
<h1>Here comes a plot</h1>
some Text
<div class=“bk-root">
<div class=“plotdiv">
{{script | safe }}
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Also refer to the CSS file to see the correct order/nesting of classes.

Answer (score 1):

`autoload_server` had an issue in `0.12.1` that prevented the correct enclosing `<div class="bk-root">` from appearing. This issue was fixed in `0.12.2`, you can either upgrade, or put them in by hand as the other issue demonstrates.